# Flatten/smooth/reduce noise in SRTM elevation maps

Tags: grass-gis, elevation, srtm

Is it possible to "flatten" some areas in an elevation map using GRASS?

For example I have an elevation map of Iraq. I'd like to smooth out the mostly flat areas while still keeping things like rivers (tigris & euphrates), hills and mountains.

Comment: You might have a look at `r.param.scale`. This module prepares geomorphology characteristics (slopes, peaks, valleys, etc), with user defined threshold parameters. So you could set the maximum slope that you consider "flat" and extract all those areas.

Comment: Just curious: are you aware of the recent NASADEM release with notable quality improvements? There is also a new addon for it: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/manuals/addons/r.in.nasadem.html

Comment: @markusN interesting, is that included in GRASS 7.8.3?

Comment: As it is an addon, you need to install it with "g.extension" or using the graphical user interface under "Settings" > "Addon extensions".